# problem with docker directory - it stops executing all commands

Tags: node.js, linux, typescript, docker, docker-compose

Yesterday, I was trying to create a shell script inside the Docker environment. Everything was working fine, but today all the projects are not working, even the ones I did not touch yesterday, and they were working without any problems before.

Today, nothing is working!.

All the files in the host's root are copied correctly to "/app" in the container, but the error occurs when executing the command.

this is the error:
[image]

and this "/app" directory , All files are in it!:

[image]

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:21.1.0-bookworm as test-node-image
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
ARG NODE_ENV
RUN npm install -g typescript
RUN npm install
COPY ./ /app
ENV PORT 3000
EXPOSE $PORT
CMD [ "npm","run","start" ]
```

package.json file:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tsx": "^4.4.0",
    "typescript": "^5.3.2"
  },
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsx watch src/index.ts"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },

  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true,
    "experimentalSpecifierResolution": "node"
  },
  "watchOptions": {
    "watchFile": "dynamicPriorityPolling",
    "watchDirectory": "dynamicPriorityPolling",
    "excludeDirectories": ["**/node_modules", "dist"]
  }
}
```

What did I do yesterday?
I tried creating a shellscript in the watch.sh file and then executing it with these commands:

> docker exec test-app chmod +x watch.sh
>
> docker exec test-app ./watch.sh

I recently started learning Docker and I don't know what to do to get it back to how it was. I hope I can find help

Comment: What does the `watch.sh` script do? and try to access the container using `docker exec -it [CONTAINER_ID] /bin/bash` and check manually the file exist with proper permissions (important)

Comment: I was following the AI's suggestions and now the AI ​​has no solution to the problem it caused. These commands.. it did not work and gave me an error

Comment: npx chokidar 'src/**/*.ts' | xargs -r exec tsc --incremental --project tsconfig.json

Comment: npx chokidar './src/**/*.ts' --initial --command "docker exec <container_name> tsc --noEmit false"

Comment: If you delete the container and run it from 0 again, does it work? And your watch script is very strange. Looks like you try to do hot reload? why do you do it that way? there are other ways which are considered best practice

Comment: I deleted them all, rebuilt them, and even tried changing the image version, nothing worked. The container is not running, but the files seem to have been copied to the container and not deleted, as is clear in the picture. I do not know what happened. All the projects that were working well and I did not change anything in them now give the same error!

Comment: What if you exec into the container and run the failed command manually?

Comment: How do I execute the command in a stopped container? .. the contaioner is not running

Comment: Finally, it worked. The problem was not from the commands. I restarted windows and everything returned to normal. It seems that the problem is with starting the Docker application from the beginning. It did not start correctly previously. This cost me a lot of time and deleted many projects and images on it!. Thank you very much for trying to help me.